# Server-side warning: Aggregation query used without partition key

Tags: c++, cassandra, warnings, cassandra-3.0

While using the C/C++ driver of Cassandra, I at times see these kind of messages popping up in my console:

```
1460937092.140 [WARN] (src/response.cpp:51:char*
      cass::Response::decode_warnings(char*, size_t)):
      Server-side warning: Aggregation query used without partition key
```

Wondering whether someone knows what that means. What should I be looking for in my code that could generate this error, or is it just something on the server side that I have no control over?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That warning is telling you that you are doing a select using a  user defined aggregate without a partition key. That may be one that is built in like avg, count, min, max or could've one of your own.

An example:

```
select avg(temperature) from weather_data;
```

Vs

```
select avg(temperature) from weather_data where id = 1;
```

The first example would scan all rows of data in the cluster and could be a serious performance hit. If there are enough rows, the query could time out.

The second will only scan a single partition of data which keeps the query to one server and is the recommended usage.

Comment: Ah. That's the `count(*)`... that worked well with thrift and just returned the number of rows. Or maybe not... But I see the statement causing the warning now.